# Find the orthogonal projection P on L.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L=<3e_3+2e_1,e_5>$ and $x=(2,1,3,2,-6,8,2,1,0,0,0,...)$. Find $\|Px\|$ where P is the orthogonal projection on L (Do not forget that the formula for Px orthogonal vectors need length 1)

I missed the example in class on how to do this. I just need an answer for this one if you'd all be so kind! Then I can use it to do the rest of them. I just need to see a run through of one example. Thanks!

Ok

$$\frac{2\cdot 2+3\cdot 3}{4+9}(2,0,3,0,..)+\frac{-6}{1}(0,0,0,0,1,0,...) = (2,0,3,0,-6,0,..)$$
Now $$\|(2,0,3,0,-6,0,...)\|_2 = \sqrt{4+9+36} = 7$$

Comment: The projection formula for a vector $\vec w$ onto the subspace $\operatorname{span}(\vec v)$ is given by $\operatorname{proj}_{\vec v}\vec w = \dfrac {\langle \vec w, \vec v\rangle}{\langle \vec v, \vec v\rangle}\vec v$.  It's easy enough to derive by drawing a picture.

Comment: It'd be great to know **what vector space** we're talking about here ! I suspect though that it could be the vector space of all (real? complex?) infinite sequences, but then what inner product are we given ?

Comment: $l^2$ hang on i'm going to edit my question, just want to see if i've done it right!